# How can I speed up an analytic chatbot that's based on Langchain (with agents and tools) and Streamlit and disable its intermediate steps?

Tags: python, chatbot, streamlit, langchain, large-language-model

I created an analytic chatbot using Langchain (with tools and agents) for the backend and Streamlit for the frontend. It works, but for some users' questions, it takes too much time to output anything. If I look at the output of intermediate steps, I can see that the chatbot tries to print out all relevant rows in the output. For example, below, the chatbot found 40 relevant comments and printed them out in one of its intermediate steps one by one (it takes up to one minute).

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to speed up this process?
2. How can I disable the intermediate output of the chatbot? (I already put `return_intermediate_steps=False`, `verbose=False`, and `expand_new_thoughts=False`, but the chatbot still shows intermediate steps.)

Code for chatbot:

```
def load_data(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path)

if st.sidebar.button('Use Data'):
    # If button is clicked, load the EDW.csv file
    st.session_state["df"] = load_data('./data/EDW.csv')
uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Choose a CSV file", type="csv")


if "df" in st.session_state:

    msgs = StreamlitChatMessageHistory()
    memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(chat_memory=msgs, 
                                            return_messages=True, 
                                            k=5, 
                                            memory_key="chat_history", 
                                            output_key="output")
    
    if len(msgs.messages) == 0 or st.sidebar.button("Reset chat history"):
        msgs.clear()
        msgs.add_ai_message("How can I help you?")
        st.session_state.steps = {}

    avatars = {"human": "user", "ai": "assistant"}

    # Display a chat input widget
    if prompt := st.chat_input(placeholder=""):
        st.chat_message("user").write(prompt)

        llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
                        deployment_name = "gpt-4",
                        model_name = "gpt-4",
                        openai_api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"],
                        openai_api_version = os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"],
                        openai_api_base = os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"],
                        temperature = 0, 
                        streaming=True
                        )
        
        max_number_of_rows = 40
        agent_analytics_node = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
                                                        llm, 
                                                        st.session_state["df"], 
                                                        verbose=False, 
                                                        agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
                                                        reduce_k_below_max_tokens=True, # to not exceed token limit 
                                                        max_execution_time = 20,
                                                        early_stopping_method="generate", # will generate a final answer after the max_execution_time has been surpassed
                                                        # max_iterations=2, # to cap an agent at taking a certain number of steps
                                                    )
        tool_analytics_node = Tool(
                                return_intermediate_steps=False,
                                name='Analytics Node',
                                func=agent_analytics_node.run,
                                description=f''' 
                                            This tool is useful when you need to answer questions about data stored in a pandas dataframe, referred to as 'df'. 
                                            'df' comprises the following columns: {st.session_state["df"].columns.to_list()}.
                                            Here is a sample of the data: {st.session_state["df"].head(5)}.
                                            When working with df, ensure not to output more than {max_number_of_rows} rows at once, either in intermediate steps or in the final answer. This is because df could contain too many rows, which could potentially overload memory, for example instead of `df[df['survey_comment'].str.contains('wet', na=False, case=False)]['survey_comment'].tolist()` use `df[df['survey_comment'].str.contains('wet', na=False, case=False)]['survey_comment'].head({max_number_of_rows}).tolist()`.
                                            '''
                            )              
        
        tools = [tool_analytics_node] 
        chat_agent = ConversationalChatAgent.from_llm_and_tools(llm=llm, tools=tools, return_intermediate_steps=False)
    
        
        executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
                                                        agent=chat_agent,
                                                        tools=tools,
                                                        memory=memory,
                                                        return_intermediate_steps=False,
                                                        handle_parsing_errors=True,
                                                        verbose=False,
                                                    )
        
        with st.chat_message("assistant"):
          
            st_cb = StreamlitCallbackHandler(st.container(), expand_new_thoughts=False)
            response = executor(prompt, callbacks=[st_cb])
            st.write(response["output"])
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to to optimise it (at least that I know of), is to have a complete overhaul overhaul of the architecture, and use a RAG model.
If you don't know, RAG stands for Retrieval Augmented Generation, where basically you give an AI a document, and it will create a vector database on it, and answer questions about it. While this does use Langchain, it also uses Open AI, and I'm afraid I have never tried a way with out Open AI because you need it to create Embeddings, which are crucial for ragging.

I have attached some code that uses Streamlit and Langchain, which gives the user a file-drop box and then you can ask any questions on the document (like Chat PDF). It only works for txt and pdf files.

```
import streamlit as st
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pickle
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback
import os
import openai

# Sidebar contents
with st.sidebar:
    st.title(' LLM Chat App')
    st.markdown('''
    ## About
    This app is an LLM-powered chatbot built using:
    - [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/)
    - [LangChain](https://python.langchain.com/)
    - [OpenAI](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models) LLM model
 
    ''')
    st.write('Created for Non-Profit Purposes')

load_dotenv()

def main():
    st.header("Chat with PDF ")

    # upload a PDF file
    pdf = st.file_uploader("Upload your PDF", type='pdf')

    if pdf is not None:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf)

        text = ""
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()

        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
            chunk_size=1000,
            chunk_overlap=200,
            length_function=len
        )
        chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text=text)

        store_name = pdf.name[:-4]
        st.write(f'{store_name}')

        if os.path.exists(f"{store_name}.pkl"):
            with open(f"{store_name}.pkl", "rb") as f:
                VectorStore = pickle.load(f)
        else:
            embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPEN_AI_KEY)
            VectorStore = FAISS.from_texts(chunks, embedding=embeddings)
            with open(f"{store_name}.pkl", "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(VectorStore, f)

        query = st.text_input("Ask questions about your PDF file:")

        if query:
            docs = VectorStore.similarity_search(query=query, k=3)
            llm = OpenAI(openai_api_key=OPEN_AI_KEY)
            chain = load_qa_chain(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff")
            with get_openai_callback() as cb:
                response = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
                st.write(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(I apologise for the poor reading of the file, but I think you get the idea)
Of course you are doing something very different, but you can edit out code as you please so that you don't have to insert the file at the start. This architecture might not work with you at all, you might be doing something completely different, but hopefully now you may have been inspired to do RAG or something similar, something that you could do more research on. Hope this helps